# Http Request error Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, http

i am trying to post http request and i have use thread and asyncTask to avoid this erorr

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

but i get new error:

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

when i used this code

```
 Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"loop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
            post.setHeader("Authorization","OAuth realm=\"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json\",status=\"aay%20from%20pstman8\",oauth_consumer_key=\"xx\",oauth_token=\"xx\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1420004144\",oauth_nonce=\"2neFPPabcd2neFPPabcd2neFPPabcdqq\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"ZbexXD3Npgy6pzQ3u3mnbDNFHcw%3D\"");
            try
            {

                client.execute(post);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should post code snippet under the question. Most probably you're trying to use looper inside regular Java Thread, if so you need to pass looper in it so you can callback. Although not sure why you need a Thread AND AsyncTask, should be good with one or another

Comment: see new update i have post code

Comment: http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/  there is sample framework for how you can do it.

Comment: hmmm, i get another error

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are trying to display toast message from secondary thread.

Please call Toast.makeText from the UI thread:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! Everyone talks about "runOnUiThread" and background threads vs UI threads, but no one shows how to actually use it. You are great! ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using pure Thread like this for simple HTTP request, you have many options for this, if you're writing an app which will do many http calls, I'd suggest using some 3rd party networking library from the beginning and not spending any time for developing it yourself. Take a look at Volley for Android for example. If you just want to have one-time call then use AsyncTask like so:

```
public class MyTwitterCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, {needed data}> { 
     @Override
     protected {needed data} doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
        post.setHeader("Authorization","OAuth realm=\"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json\",status=\"aay%20from%20pstman8\",oauth_consumer_key=\"xx\",oauth_token=\"xx\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1420004144\",oauth_nonce=\"2neFPPabcd2neFPPabcd2neFPPabcdqq\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"ZbexXD3Npgy6pzQ3u3mnbDNFHcw%3D\"");
       //TODO Execute call and extract response to {needed data}
    return {needed data}
}
```

Then from your activity or fragment call:
`new MyTwitterCall().execute();`

Comment: what do you mean about {needed data} ??

Comment: whatever you're trying to return from this call to your client, I'm not sure what it is, just replace this with object you're extracting from response

Comment: if you're trying to make changes to UI from any background thread you want to wrap it the way @Prem is suggesting. But this is bad practice to post to ui thread from background thread before it's finished. Anyways there are few more callbacks you can override to do it with AsyncTask. override onPostExecute() to change your UI when network call is done. And override onProgressUpdate() if you want to post incremental updates to UI, then from doInBackground call publishProgress()